# Gorm Preload Not working with condition. It Works with Where caluse and not without it

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have using gorm here is my model

```
type Stock struct {
    ID           uint      `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    CreatedAt    time.Time `gorm:"default:current_timestamp" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt    time.Time `gorm:"default:current_timestamp" json:"updated_at"`
    Name         string
    Symbol       string
    CustomSymbol string
    ScriptType   string
    Industry     string
    ISIN         string `gorm:"unique"`
    Fno          bool
    Daily        []Daily
    Weekly       []Weekly
    Ohlc         []Ohlc
}

type Daily struct {
    ID          uint      `gorm:"autoIncrement" json:"id"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time `gorm:"default:current_timestamp" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time `gorm:"default:current_timestamp" json:"updated_at"`
    StockId     uint      `gorm:"not null;primaryKey" json:"stock_id"`
    Open        decimal.Decimal
    High        decimal.Decimal
    Low         decimal.Decimal
    Close       decimal.Decimal
    AdjClose    decimal.Decimal
    Volume      int
    Timestamp   int             `gorm:"not null;primaryKey" json:"timestamp"`
    Rs          decimal.Decimal `gorm:"not null;default:0" json:"rs"`
    BarComplete bool            `gorm:"not null;default:true" json:"bar_complete"`
}

type Weekly struct {
    ID          uint      `gorm:"autoIncrement" json:"id"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time `gorm:"default:current_timestamp" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time `gorm:"default:current_timestamp" json:"updated_at"`
    StockId     uint      `gorm:"not null;primaryKey" json:"stock_id"`
    Open        decimal.Decimal
    High        decimal.Decimal
    Low         decimal.Decimal
    Close       decimal.Decimal
    AdjClose    decimal.Decimal
    Volume      int
    Timestamp   int             `gorm:"not null;primaryKey" json:"timestamp"`
    Rs          decimal.Decimal `gorm:"not null;default:0" json:"rs"`
    BarComplete bool            `gorm:"not null;default:true" json:"bar_complete"`
}
```

Below query is working as expected preloading desired data.

```
db.Preload("Weekly", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
            return db.Order("timestamp desc").Limit(ohlcCount)
        }).Where("id = ?", stockId).Find(&stocks)
```

However when I want to get all stocks with there Weekly data preloaded, that gives me empty array for Weekly.

```
initializers.DB.Preload("Weekly", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
            return db.Order("timestamp desc").Limit(ohlcCount)
        }).Find(&stocks)
```

If I don't write inner conditon it gets required data. But It is working with Where caluse and not without it. Looking for any help.

Comment: Are these same databases btw ?

    db.Preload 
 
    initializers.DB.Preload

Comment: Try to enable logging and check the generated queries in both cases, maybe you get better hints on wht's going on. However, you might be able to use `where("1=1")` if no other solution is found.

Comment: @levniko Yes same database, just forgot to modify for question in 1 statement. I am using in another file, so referencing it like that.

Comment: @VMC where("1=1") also does not work. Will log and check queries. I feeling the problem is scanning, rather than query but still will check.

Comment: initializers.DB.Debug().Preload("Weekly", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    return db.Order("timestamp desc").Limit(ohlcCount)
}).Find(&stocks)


Can you try this and check the sql query that created by gorm ?@HimanshuPandey